# How to find the ASCII Code of a give character using functions in C?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void ascii()
{
  //code goes here
}

int main()
{
    int b;
    char a;
    b=ascii(a);
    printf("%d",b);//Expecting the ASCII Value of a to printed.
    return 0;
}
```

Expecting the printf statement to give the ASCII Value of a.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: To be honest, it actually depends on your system. Most systems today uses ASCII encoding which means you don't have to do anything. If you are running on a system which *doesn't* use ASCII, and you want to convert whatever encoding the system uses to ASCII then it's a bit more work, but it's not impossible (or hard really) if you know the systems encoding and have an ASCII table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you simply assign your `char` to an integer variable with proper type casting?

```
char c = 'a';
int  i = (int) c;
```

Would that work?

Comment: It served my purpose. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for a function, like `ascii()`. For this purpose, it is kind of *overkill*, If I may say so.

Simply use

```
char x = 'a';
printf("Symbol table index of %c is %d\n", x, x);
```

---

<sup>Note that this only works if your platform uses ASCII - for an IBM system with EBCDIC character set for example this would not return the ASCII value of the character, and you would need to use a lookup table instead.</sup>

Comment: Note that this only works if your platform uses ASCII - for an IBM system with EBCDIC character set for example this would not return the ASCII value of the character, and you would need to use a lookup table instead.

Comment: @PaulR I see the point, very True. So, what disclaimer should I add to my answer? Can you help me with the words?

Comment: @PaulR I don't think you'd be particularly interested in knowing the ASCII values on such a system. Unless the purpose of the program is to print out asciitable.com or some such.

Comment: I'm probably being overly-pedantic, but you can just copy and paste my comment into your answer if you like, as a footnote. Your answer is fine though otherwise.

Comment: @NatashaDutta Simply change your output to `printf("Symbol table index of %c is %d\n", x, x);` to sate the pedants.

Comment: I actually need the function to use in an other program. This function makes THAT other program easy... That's the reason I asked.